# Jasper Report print group values in different pages

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am facing this basic problem while using iReport 4.1.3 . I have two tables 'orders' and 'order_details'.
I map various products in the cart against each order in order_details. eg :
In the orders table I have :

order_id
123
456

and in the order_details table I will have :
order_id product_id
123             abc1
123              abc2
456              efg1
456              efg2
456              efg3

I created the following jrxml in ireport :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="merchant_invoice" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
        <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
        <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
        <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
        <parameter name="order_ids" class="java.lang.String">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
        </parameter>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[select
    o.order_id,od.product_id
    from cscart_orders o
    inner join cscart_order_details od on od.order_id=o.order_id
    where o.order_id in ($P{order_ids})]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="order_id" class="java.math.BigInteger"/>
        <field name="product_id" class="java.math.BigInteger"/>
        <group name="order_id_group" isStartNewPage="true" isReprintHeaderOnEachPage="true">
            <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{order_id}]]></groupExpression>
            <groupHeader>
                <band height="25">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="6" y="3" width="380" height="20"/>
                        <textElement/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["header for order_id "+$F{order_id}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </band>
            </groupHeader>
            <groupFooter>
                <band height="25">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="8" y="3" width="291" height="20"/>
                        <textElement/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Footer for order id : "+$F{order_id}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </band>
            </groupFooter>
        </group>
        <background>
            <band splitType="Stretch"/>
        </background>
        <detail>
            <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="8" y="4" width="270" height="20"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Products with id :"+$F{product_id}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </detail>
    </jasperReport>
```

But when I preview it using parameters as '123,456' , I only get a single page with details for only first order ie order 123.
I'm not getting where am I doing wrong.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are selecting multiple order ids then query should be like this

```
select
o.order_id,od.product_id
from cscart_orders o
inner join cscart_order_details od on od.order_id=o.order_id
where $X{IN,o.order_id,order_ids}
```

and class of parameter order_ids should "java.util.Collection" and you can also give default value expression

```
 <parameter name="order_ids" class="java.util.Collection"> 
 <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"123","456"}))]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

Comment: My framework is developed such that every single parameter has to be passed only as String.
Besides , Passing parameter as Collection still not helping.

Comment: I have updated answer and try to give default value expression for parameter in iReport.